# Сonvert list values to dictionary as key and value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose there is a list: `['1604780184', '10', '1604780194', '0', '1604780319', '99', '1604780320', '0']`

You need to get a result like: `{'1604780184': '10', '1604780194': '0', '1604780319': '99', '1604780320': '0'}`

Now I have so:

```
rline = ['1604780184', '10', '1604780194', '0', '1604780319', '99', '1604780320', '0']
total = {}
print(f"My list: {rline}")

while rline:
    total[rline[0:2][0]] = rline[0:2][1]
    del rline[0:2]

print(f"Dictionary: {total}")
```

Please advise a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most concise (and probably the best) way might be:

```
result = dict(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
```

What it actually does is make use of some pattern your list follows and some builtin functions! Since every even index is a value-to-be and odd index a key-to-be, its easier to just slice and separate them. Then you can use `zip()` to form a collection of these separated values and then call `dict()` constructor to pull a dictionary out of it!

Comment: Please explain what it does, in 99% of the cases you learn to the OP something, because if not he would have done it. So tell him what your does ;)

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about ```zip()``` :)

Comment: @Artem Baranov consider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 3):

I do not like to change a list while iterating over it. I'd prefer do this way:

```
i = 0
while i < len(rline):
  total[rline[i]] = rline[i+1]
  i = i + 2

print(f"Dictionary: {total}")
```